# Instrumentation

Tags: java, assembly, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm

I am new to ASM(byte code manipulation kit) and am using it to instrument java byte code. I want to access the methods of a class and change their access modifiers using ASM. Does someone have an idea about how to achieve this? I know that calling visitMethod would help but do not know how to do that exactly Any information on this would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, if I would like to just print all the methods, how do I do that? Thanks once again..

Comment: I believe you got an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm-guide.pdf

See pages 16 and 22.